# Is there a way to make whitespace visible in the Xcode editor?

Tags: xcode, editor, whitespace

I want the tabs and spaces to be visible in Xcode. Is this possible? I can't find it under preferences.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Xcode 6.x and earlier:

View -> Text -> Show Spaces

View -> Text -> Show Control Characters

Comment: Thanks. That does show the spaces.  Oddly Show control characters is not making the tabs visible.  And seeing how XCode shows spaces I may reconsider my desire to use this. :-(

Comment: I⌴agree,⌴it's⌴annoying⌴to⌴read⌴through⌴your⌴code⌴thinking⌴that⌴your⌴font⌴may⌴be⌴missing⌴some⌴characters…

Comment: For Xcode 13 beta 2: Editor -> Invisibles

Answer (score 104):

Editor -> Show Invisibles in Xcode 4

Comment: @JavierSedano I've checked around, and it seems there is no reasonable way to achieve what you're asking as of this writing. This is because common characters such as brackets are coupled to the same font color setting as invisibles.

Comment: I suggest Apple moves settings to the settings pane. Else it's Microsoft or Google. 

Answer (score 58):

In Xcode 7 and later, this command has moved to the Editor menu:

Editor > Show Invisibles

or

Editor > Hide Invisible

### Edit

As of Xcode 12.1, the menu item is now simply called ***Invisibles***. It's checked when invisibles are shown, and un-checked when they are not shown.

Further, it looks like Xcode now uses very light blue dots for spaces, and bold light blue dots for the spaces that correspond to your tab positions, which is very nice.

Comment: Is it possible to change the characters used to represent the whitespaces and tabs ? Visual studio uses a simple dot which is more viewable than the one used by xcode.

Comment: I don't know. Sorry.

Comment: It looks like newer versions of Xcode use a dot for spaces now (I'm running Xcode 12.1 and spaces show as dots, with every 4th space {when using 4-character space-based indentation} is bold.)

Answer (score 32):

You can also use [defaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/defaults.1.html) to read/write to the Xcode `plist`

This is used/tested in Xcode `6.1`

## GUI

`Editor->Show Invisibles`

## CLI

### Turn it on

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode DVTTextShowInvisibleCharacters 1
```

### Turn it off

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode DVTTextShowInvisibleCharacters 0
```

Answer (score 18):

Since Xcode `11`:

In the menu check/uncheck:
`Editor -> Invisibles`

Answer (score 18):

It is under **Editor -> Invisibles**. You can **check** it to show or **uncheck** it to hide them.

---

#### A note about the macOS 

In the mac environment, you can search for any menu option under the **Help** menu, then it will open the exact menu path you are looking for. For example, searching for **invi**sibles results in this:

[image: Demo]

Comment: Props for telling people about searching for Mac menu shortcuts.

Answer (score 2):

You can also enter a white space into the search field, this will highlight all white spaces in yellow temporarily. I found this accidentally here, where Marty asked the other way around: [What are these yellow spacers in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23638320/what-are-these-yellow-spacers-in-xcode)

Comment: Won't that only match the specific TYPE of whitespace you're searching for? (spaces or tabs or non-breaking spaces, but never all different kinds of white-space)

Comment: ...although you could create a regular expression search that would find all different kinds of whitespace..