# What are these yellow spacers in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, xcode5

Just came back to my desk and Xcode keeps highlighting/underlining white space in files.  If I type something it goes away, but if I switch tabs and come back, they reappear.

UPDATE: this isn't caused by the "show invisibles" option.  That looks different (try it).

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You seem to have a search active. Look in your search bar at the top and you should find a " " character. Xcode is highlighting all instances of the matching space character.

Comment: This is correct (`Xcode > Editor > Show Invisibles` looks much, much worse).

Comment: Great answer!  I was like, "What the heck did I do?"

Answer (score 0):

Go to Editor > Hide Invisibles in the toolbar. It's showing all the invisible characters in the document, including spaces.