# How do I get Xcode to show dots instead of spaces in the editor?

Tags: xcode

How do I get dots instead of spaces in the Xcode editor similar to this image below?

The dots on the left side of the code.

[image]

Comment: In the menu it’s something like “Editor -> Invisible Characters” or something like that.

Comment: https://sarunw.com/posts/how-to-show-hide-whitespace-in-xcode/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to make whitespace visible in the Xcode editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873712/is-there-a-way-to-make-whitespace-visible-in-the-xcode-editor)